# How to get data from the user login to display and update the username on the main page?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

Here is where I have already have a Get request on the login page to grab data from the front end

```
  //String url = 'http://localhost:9000/user/john.doe@email.com';
  String url = "http://10.0.2.2:9000/user/john.doe@email.com/";
  Future<int> makeLoginRequest() async {
    var response = await http
        .get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    var userData = json.decode(response.body);
    int userId = userData['Id'];

    return userId;
  }
```

And below here I am trying to update the username dynamically to display on the main page from the login.
How would I return the id from the user logging in here?

```
String name = "";
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    getNamePreference().then(updateName);

  }

Future<String> getNamePreference() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String name = prefs.getString("name");

  return name;
}

void updateName(String incomingName) {
    setState(() {
      name = incomingName;

    });

}
```

Comment: Where are you saving value of name key in SharedPreference?

Comment: It is on a Rest api with data from mysql database
{"Id":1,"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","city":"los angeles","age":23,"gender":"male","professional":"student","email":"john.doe@email.com","username":"jdoe","password":"abc123","createdAt":"2020-04-24 19:45:38","deletedAt":null,"id":1}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save firstName in sharedpreference in Login Screen like below..

```
String url = "http://10.0.2.2:9000/user/john.doe@email.com/";
  void makeLoginRequest() async {
    var response = await http
        .get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    var userData = json.decode(response.body);
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString("name", userData['firstName'];);
     ...
     //code for navigate to main screen
      ...
      }
```

call this method in onClick event of Login Button
then Get this value of key "name" in main Screen like below..

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
String name = prefs.getString("name");
```

Please add above two lines in initState() method

after that you can use `name` variable to display Name in main screen.

Comment: Would they both still be using Future<String>?

Comment: Not require Future here

Comment: I get an error for userData. We have to define it? And for set string we have to return it?

Comment: PLease upvote and accept my answer so other user can get benefit from it